# Setting a character limit on a prompt box Javascript

Tags: javascript, prompt, simplemodal

I would like to know if there is a way to pre-set the length of the characters in the javascript prompt. So that I can enter only one character and no more

```js
var carattere = prompt("inserte a character");


console.log(carattere);

if (carattere=="a" || carattere=="e" || carattere=="i" || carattere=="o" || carattere=="u") {
    window.alert("the character is a Vowel");
}else if(carattere=="y"){
    window.alert("Y can be consonant or vowel");
}else{
    window.alert("the character is a consonant");
}
```

Comment: I don't think thats possible using plain `prompt`. But https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt suggests an alternative: `dialog` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog haven't tested it but from what I see it should be possible to built your own dialog with your own textbox and set the `maxlength` to `1`. You could use the old `prompt` as fallback for browsers that doesnt support the dialog but it seems that most modern browsers support it: https://caniuse.com/?search=dialog

Answer (score 1):

Since [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) stores a string by default, You could check for the length of the prompt using [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length). Like this:

```js
const carattere = prompt("Insert a character");


if (carattere.length === 1) {
  if (carattere === "a" || carattere === "e" || carattere === "i" || carattere === "o" || carattere === "u") {
    window.alert("The character is a Vowel");
  } else if (carattere === "y") {
    window.alert("Y can be consonant or vowel");
  } else {
    window.alert("The character is a consonant");
  }
} else {
  console.log("Please limit the input to a single character");
}
```

**Note**: Typing a number character gets identified as consonant. You might want to add an additional check (like a regular expression) to account for that.